# There was an issue resolving the dependency tree for the artifact

Tags: mulesoft, mule-connector, mule-sdk

I am following Mulesoft tutorials to create a connector with Mule SDK(https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/getting-started). I followed the steps but when I try to include the connector dependency(https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/getting-started#add-your-connector-to-studio), i get the below error: 
There was an issue resolving the dependency tree for the artifact

Any pointers to fix this issue?

Comment: Please post the complete error message -as text- with as much details as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dependemcy what you try to add does not exist. It may happen because training document is obsolete and does not have refernce to recent modules. Or modules were removed and replaced fo some reason.

Please, provide more detail error log and then it should be easy to determine what exactly mdoule is absent.

Answer (score 0):

Did you execute the Maven install command (`mvn clean install`) before trying to use the artifact in the application pom?

Comment: Yes I did. As of right now
Installed new version of Anypoint Studio.

Installed IntelliJ.

Tried same tutorial and then tried to install connector..

Got the below error:

Failed to execute goal org.mule.runtime.plugins:mule-extensions-maven-plugin:1.1.6:extension-model (default-extension-model) on project mule-connector-sample: Execution default-extension-model of goal org.mule.runtime.plugins:mule-extensions-maven-plugin:1.1.6:extension-model failed: Trying to add the 'CONNECTIVITY' Error to the Component 'retrieveInfo' but the Extension doesn't declare it.